# Given a number n, print the first number of the series greater than or equal to n

Tags: c++

I am trying to find an efficient way to, given a number n, print the first number of the following series greater or equal to n:

0, 0+1, 0+1+2, 0+1+2+3, 0+1+2+3+4, ... = **0, 1, 3, 6, 10, ...**

For example, 2 would return 3, and 7 (or 8, or 9) would return 10.

There's surely a smart way to solve it... Could you help me? Thanks in advance!

The following code returns the correct solutions, but it is not efficient enough for this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    while(cin >> n){
        int m = 0;
        for(int i = 1;m < n; ++i){
            m = m + i;
        }
        cout << m << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: one way to solve is using **Memoization**, it is a term describing an optimization technique where you cache previously computed results, and return the cached result when the same computation is needed again.

Comment: Thanks @AviatorX, could you show me an example on how to code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing triangular numbers!

`y = (x*(x + 1)) / 2;`

To get the next number in the series given y, you could solve for x

`x = ceil((sqrt(1+8y)-1)/2);`

Then throw x back into the 1st formula to get your answer!

This is a good approach for large numbers but may not be ideal for smaller numbers

Comment: Yes, I know, but how can I use this in the code (so it becomes more efficient)?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to write program for Arithmetic progression (AP) i.e. sum of first **n** numbers

```
int main(){
    int n;
    while(cin >> n){
        int m = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
        cout << m << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok but, given a number, how can I print the first number in the AP greater than or equal to that number (in an efficient way)?